# URL strings in Variables

Tags: c#, asp.net, url, stored-procedures, url-rewriting

ASP.net 
Please help me doing this.
I have one URL : localhost:8979/shop/books/science-fiction/USA

I want to store all strings after shop in to variables:

Ex: I need 'books' in variable 'b'
    I need 'science fiction' in variable 's'
    and 'USA' in variable 'c'

Please note that I need to remove "-"(dash) from URL and replace it with space. because i need to check it with my database.

Thanks, Please help.

Comment: Which language/tool/server? Take a pen and a piece of paper, write b=books, s=science fiction, c=USA.

Comment: Thank you for reply. Language: Asp.net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're coding in C#, you have your URL in a string variable named `url`, and `shop` is always the second element of your URL:

```
var urlParts = url.Replace('-', ' ').Split('/');
b = urlParts[2];
s = urlParts[3];
c = urlParts[4];
```

If `shop` can be variable, replace the last three lines with:

```
for (int i = 0; i < urlParts.Length; i++) {
    if (urlParts[i] == "shop") {
        b = urlParts[i + 1];
        s = urlParts[i + 2];
        d = urlParts[i + 3];
    }
}
```

None of these checks for badly formed URLs--if it's possible that the URL will not be formatted as you expect, you'll need to add some error checking.

Comment: Shop is my aspx page name, which comes after domain name, in URL